# Code to restrict search to records within a date range and no more recent than that range

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, aggregate

I am searching a table of services provided for each worksite (from the worksite table that meet certain criteria). I want the count of services provided for each worksite where the count is for worksites that have had a service in a specific date range and no services after this range.

[image]

My query retrieves records since a specific date and I cannot figure out the code to do the date range criteria. I tried to use WHERE MAX() as part of the subquery but that gave me an error:

> SQL Error (147) :An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Any advice is appreciated.

```
select
emp.company,
emp.col_empid,
emp.siccode,
empworksite.worksiteid,
empworksite.location,
empworksite.city,
empworksite.zip,
(select
    count (col_worksiteid)
    from serviceplan
    where serviceplan.col_worksiteid = empworksite.worksiteid
    AND serviceplan.servicecode IN ('EJO','JF','SE','JT')
    AND serviceplan.createdate >= '10/01/2022 00:00') as count_of_services
from empworksite
join emp on emp.col_empid = empworksite.col_empid
join tbl_empxregistration on tbl_empxregistration.col_empid = empworksite.col_empid
WHERE empworksite.lwia = '14' AND emp.joborders = '1' AND tbl_empxregistration.col_reg_type_id = '3' AND emp.typeemp = '5' AND emp.siccode NOT LIKE '11%' AND empworksite.active = '1'
ORDER By count_of_services DESC
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected outputs to make a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you put the exact query you wrote that isn't working as well? And, as Xedni said, sample data and expected results are a sure fire way to get a good answer. In any case, WHERE MAX() is not the syntax, HAVING MAX().

Comment: For starters, you have no GROUP BY in your subquery with `COUNT(col_worksiteid)`.

Comment: Ok, data and expected results added..

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to count services provided in FY2023 for each worksite that had no services in FY2024, where FY2023 and FY2024 are ranges of dates?

Try this

```
select e.col_empworksite, count(s2023.servicecode)
from empworksite e
left outer join serviceplan s2023 on s2023.col_empworksite = e.col_empworksite and s2023.createdate between <FY2023_RANGE>
where not exists (select 1 from serviceplan s2024 where s2024.createdate between <FY2024_RANGE> and s2024.col_empworksite = s2023.col_empworksite) 
group by e.col_empworksite
```

Comment: this works, thank you but I need to restrict it by e.lwia where e.lwia = '14'. when I add that as a WHERE clause the system times out..